# King of Thieves Gem spinner

Tags: king-of-thieves

So when I'm playing and trying to steal someone else's gem, with 2 stars (about 35% chance), I don't get it. Then it gives you an option to re-spin. I spent 75 orbs to re-spin 4 times, and all 4 times **they land in the same general area!** (like within 5% of the circle). That makes me wonder, is the spinner time based (can I time a re-spin to maximize my chances) or is it purely random based off of other people's spins and an algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a massive discussion in the king of thieves community about the spinner being rigged. Some say it is rigged, some say it's just your mind playing tricks on you.
Either way, it's supposed to be random and not based on what other people spin. Pure % chance.

[First discussion](http://forum.kingofthieves.com/topic/18683-gem-stealing-spinning-wheel-is-unbalanced/)

[Second discussion](http://forum.kingofthieves.com/topic/16339-gem-spinner-is-very-fishy/)

[Minor other thread](http://forum.kingofthieves.com/topic/6431-is-gem-stealing-spinner-really-random/)

Comment: Definitely rigged. The whole game is rigged to move you to make in app purchases. Several times when I have been stumped by a dungeon and ask for a solution the solution show has been impossible...walking through fire and ignoring traps. Plus the spinner is NOT random...not even close.